# groovy.lang.missingpropertyexception no such property: groovy utils for class

Tags: groovy, soapui, assertions

In SoapUI I am trying to read response xml and perform assert equals this is //my code

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import com.eviware.soapui.support.*

 responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder
 ( 
 testRunner.testCase.testSteps["NDCIssueTKT"].testRequest.response.responseContent );
      responseHolder.declareNamespace("ns1","http://TKT.svc")
     CDATAXml = respXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//ns1:NDCIssueTKTResult")
      log.info(CDATAXml)
        CDATAXmlHolder = new XmlHolder(CDATAXml)
      errorMSG = CDATAXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//description")
          log.info("errorMSG = $errorMSG")
            assert errMSG == propTestStep.getPropertyValue("Response")
```

but I get no such property exception, can anyone help?

EDIT: based on comments

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <NDCIssueTKTResponse xmlns="TKT.svc">
         <NDCIssueTKTResult>
            <err xmlns="web2200/webservices/">
               <code>11000011</code>
               <description>FBA ERROR: incorrect quantity.</description>
               <level>200</level>
            </err>
         </NDCIssueTKTResult>
      </NDCIssueTKTResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please shows the response that you are working with.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>

-<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">


-<s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


-<NDCIssueTKTResponse xmlns="http://TKT.svc">


-<NDCIssueTKTResult>


-<err xmlns="http://web2200/webservices/">

<code>11000011</code>

<description>FBA ERROR: incorrect quantity.</description>

<level>200</level>

</err>

</NDCIssueTKTResult>

</NDCIssueTKTResponse>

</s:Body>

</s:Envelope>

Comment: This is the response.

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Script Assertion](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html) for the same request step as shown below:

**Script Assertion**

```
//Check if the response is not null or empty
assert context.response, 'response is null or empty'

//Define the expected description
def expectedDescription = 'FBA ERROR: incorrect quantity.'​
def pXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)
def actualDescription = pXml.'**'.find {it.name() == 'description'}​​
assert actualDescription == ​expectedDescription, 'Description is not matching'
```

Similarly if you want to assert `code`, do the following:

```
def expectedCode = 11000011
def actualCode = pXml.'**'.find {it.name() == 'code'}
assert actualCode == expectedCode, 'Code does not match'
```

You can quickly try online <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5117955910139904)</kbd>

**EDIT:** based on the comment by OP.
Looks like you are using `Groovy Script` Test step with a fixed value. If use `Script Assertion` as suggested, you do not have to have additional test step that you have (groovy script step).

Comment: Actually i want to check it for different values if i go for this approach i have to change the xml dynamically to the response that is generated,  hence can you tell me the way i can always change the xml i define here to pick the response xml dynamically?

Comment: Looks like you are using groovy script test step. If you use `Script Assertion` then it always handles dynamic response only. Added link in the answer - how to create script assertion if are not aware. Are you talking about the same ? or talking about expected values? Have you tried in first place? did it help?

Comment: I am doing a data driven testing so my msgs and tag will change on negative and positive data for negative there will be different error messages depending on what value i pass wrongly. but for positive i think i can handle it with Script assertion as the tags will remain same.

Comment: Ok. I would suggest to try it as base script and see if that helps. I believe you can use the above one as base and change it as needed for your case. If you find the above is helpful and answers the original question, then consider [accepting answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @user3607087, appreciate if you can accept it as answered for the original question.